# UISearchDisplayController Cancel Button Truncated?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController setup with the standard UISearchBar. I customized the font of the cancel button and it worked fine. The issue I'm having is that from search I can push a new view controller onto the stack after tapping a search result. That works seamlessly, but when I "go back" the cancel button gets truncated. I tried decreasing the font size and it makes no difference. The text starts out fine, but after navigating forward and back it gets truncated.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: trying putting the code for defining font in viewDidAppear

Comment: Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, i was just thinking, it might be because of the textfield displaying the clear button. you might have to resignFirstResponder when pushing the VC

Comment: Resign the search controller when you push? That wouldn't be a very ideal situation because then upon return you'd have to restart the search if necessary.

Comment: What kind of size is the searchable? And do you use auto layout? Try [searchBar sizeToFit];